# WPF control layout for Pomodora

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

NET and learning WPF now. I want to create a tool for Pomodoro technique to learn WPF. This is the lay out in my mind.

1. List of tasks
2. Status for the task. One tomato for every 25 mins. This is list of interactive images/buttons, in which users can take some actions like add, remove tomato.

What I am looking for is tips for laying this controls out and any words of wisdom :)

[image]

Comment: Put it as a open source project and learn from the wisdom from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would do is define what pieces of the UI need to be dynamic and what needs to be fixed. looks like from the screenshot, the top is probably fixed and the Task1... and the apples will be dynamic. So i would probably put everything in a grid and use a stackpanel with Vertical Orientation to hold all the tasks. Then each individual task would be a stackpanel with Horizontal Orientation built dynamically with it looks like a textblock to hold "Task1" and then varying amounts of images or whatever control you will be using for the apples and pencils and stuff like that.